# I really want to pick up weight I'm too skinny

Tags: diet, muscle, calories

I am a 18 year old boy which suppose to look healthy n fit and have a great built but instead I look like a broomstick and I hate that so much I have tried many things such as drinking eggs and milk daily,tablets etc I have also tried working out but I don't see an improvement I need some advice on picking up weight please help me out being skinny changes your entire lifestyle your clothes does not suit you even if you the best ones,your face is small and you just look horrible please tell me something that will really me thanks.

Comment: What's your current diet like?

Comment: Lift heavy weights--*no, heavier!*--eat more--*more eggs!*--and stop doing things that make people skinny--*stop running and playing sports and staying up all night instead of sleeping*.

Answer (score 0):

EAT GODDAMIT.

No matter how much you think you are eating it is no-where near enough.

As a Male in his young twenties I aim for like 6000 calories, your metabolism is crazy at this stage and you have to eat to its rules.

Comment: -1. We can do without the profanity, and caloric intake is highly person and activity dependent.

Comment: @JohnP as a young male his caloric intake requirements are going to be huge irregardless of whether he sits on the couch every day or runs marathons. Yes 6000 is an exaggeration but its in the right direction

Comment: That's fine, and I agree the base sentiment should be eat more, but blind exaggeration does not make for a good answer.